# C# Attempting to print array gives IndexOutOfRangeAcception Error

Tags: c#, arrays

new c# programmer here,

I am currently making a simple program to print out the first 10 times tables of a number. This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Times_tables_calculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int number;
            int counter;
            int timestable;
            int[] TimeTableList = new int[10];
            counter = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number:");
            number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            while (counter <= 10) 
            {
                timestable = (number * counter);
                TimeTableList[counter] = timestable;
                counter = (counter + 1);              
            }

            Console.WriteLine("The times tables for " + number + " are:");
            TimeTableList.ToList().ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i.ToString()));
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

However, when ever I run the program in visual studio, I get an IndexOutOfRangeAcception error on the line:

```
TimeTableList[counter] = timestable;
```

Any help would be appreciated on how I should fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: your table size is 10 but you are storing upto 11. (0-10) because of the <=10 condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either change

```
 while (counter <= 9)
```

OR

```
 while (counter < 10)
```

You are trying to access array index 11. Array index starts from 0. So you need to minus one from condition or remove `=` in condition

Comment: Both are great. Thanks. :D

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
while (counter <= 10)
```

to

```
while (counter < 10)
```

Your loops starts at 0 and ends at 10 index, that's 11 elements

Comment: That's nice to have -1 without a reason or an explanation

Answer (score 0):

counter must lower than 10 not lower equals. Array start counting at 0. Then your Elements are indexed from 0 to 9.